# opening/closing navigation drawer not working in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, side-menu, react-navigation-drawer

In my react native app I have created a side menu using Drawer Navigator which is working perfectly when I open it by swiping. But I want to do is to open it on button click. Currently I am trying to do trough navigation props, the related code is as follows:

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class HallsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isSideMenuOpen: false
    };
  } 

  renderTopView = () => {
      return(
        <View>
          <View style = {Styles.sideMenuButton}>
            <Button
              onPress = {()=> {
                if (this.state.isSideMenuOpen) {
                  {this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
                }
                else {
                  {this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerClose')}
                }
                this.setState({isSideMenuOpen: !this.state.isSideMenuOpen})
              }
            }
            title = {'Side Menu'}
            />
          </View> ..... 


export default withNavigation(HallsList);
```

But when I tap on side menu button it gets tapped but nothing happens afterwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Just change the below code parts**

Instead of `this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')`

Put `this.props.navigation.openDrawer();`

Instead of `this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerClose')`

Put `this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();`

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use :

```
this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer();
```

Instead of:

```
// to keep track of state of drawer
if (this.state.isSideMenuOpen) {
    {this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
}
else {
    {this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerClose')}
}
this.setState({isSideMenuOpen: !this.state.isSideMenuOpen})
```

Answer (score 0):

to open drawer use `this.props.navigation.openDrawer()`
and close drawer use `this.props.navigation.closeDrawer()`

[from this Document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/)

Answer (score 0):

This is working for opening and closing a toggle drawer:

```
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
```